# Not receiving email after setting MX records

Tags: dns, mx

I have domain on Bluehost named example.com and I am hosting it on AWS. I have setup an email account on Bluehost and added its MX record in AWS:

"example.com" "0 mail.example.com"

But still I am not able to receive any email on my account but I am able to send it. What are the points I have ignored?

Comment: Where is the DNS for the domain hosted? it is there that you need to edit the records. It also takes between 1-48 hours for it to take effect.

Comment: DNS are hosted on AWS Route53 and my domain is present on bluehost

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that:

- The `mail.example.com` address points to your mailserver IP address. (You can look up the IP at https://www.whatsmydns.net/ by searching for the A record for that domain.)

  If you see no IP address for that domain, you'll have to add an A record for your `mail.example.com` address that points to your mailserver's IP address, or a CNAME that points to Bluehost's email domain. Bluehost should provide the mailserver IP or domain in your email setup instructions.
- Your CNAME and MX records have propagated. A search at https://www.whatsmydns.net/ for the MX record of `example.com` should return your `mail.example.com` address worldwide. You should also see the mailserver IPs when you search for the A record for `mail.example.com`.
- Confirm that Bluehost have completed setup of your mail account.

Comment: Nick, I have done it in the same way as you mentioned like:- 
1. Created a new MX Record like 
     10  @ mail.example.com 14400
2. I have created a new MX record in AWS Route 53 with domain example.com and added MX record as above.

Still there is no luck ?

Comment: @IshanSharma Have you confirmed that `mail.example.com` points to your mailserver IP?

Comment: I have pointed *.example.com as A record to instance IP of AWS, Is it correct ?

Comment: That is correct if your subdomains are also hosted with AWS. But your `mail.example.com` domain needs to point to your mailserver with Bluehost if that is where your email is hosted. You can either: (a) set the A record for `mail.example.com` to point to the Bluehost mailserver IP and leave your current MX record unaltered, or (b) set your MX records to point to the Bluehost mail server address directly instead of to `mail.example.com`. Personally I would choose option (b) and set your MX records to whatever mail domain Bluehost recommends that you use.